# How to enable IP forwarding and port redirection in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, routes, ip, portforwarding, packet-capture

I am trying to set up mitmproxy on my Windows 10 to capture traffic from my Android phone.

I am following this [tutorial](https://blog.heckel.xyz/2013/07/01/how-to-use-mitmproxy-to-read-and-modify-https-traffic-of-your-phone/), but I am having trouble finding the corresponding commands in Windows for these Linux commands

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can  simple install Whireshark to capture your phone traffic .

https://www.wireshark.org/download.html?aktime=1551312054

and port forwarding is extra payment with some ISP make sure you have static ip .